# Can I get "&&" or "-and" to work in PowerShell?

Tags: syntax, powershell

**Note:** This question originally asked in 2009, when powershell did not have support for the `&&` operator.
In 2019, per Jay's answer, microsoft added support for `&&` and `||` in Powershell 7.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/564092/234

---

Original Question

`&&` is notoriously hard to search for on Google Search, but the best I've found is [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/webcasts/psweek/day4qanda.mspx) which says to use `-and`.

Unfortunately it doesn't give any more information, and I can't find out what I'm supposed to do with `-and` (again, a notoriously hard thing to search for).

The context I'm trying to use it in is "execute cmd1, and if successful, execute cmd2", basically this:

```
csc /t:exe /out:a.exe SomeFile.cs && a.exe
```

---

If you just want to run multiple commands on a single line and you don't care if the first one fails or not, you can use `;` For most of my purposes this is fine.

For example: `kill -n myapp; ./myapp.exe`.

Comment: PowerShell has -and and -or logical operators.
Are the operators not working the way you expect them to? If so, you can post the expression here.

Comment: See this question, it does what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917271/execute-process-conditionally-in-windows-powershell-e-g-the-and-operators

Comment: Regarding the need to perform web searches for queries with literal (and significant) symbols: [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) is useful for this.  Here are some examples that pertain to the question: [powershell &&](http://symbolhound.com/?q=powershell%20%26%26); [powershell -and](http://symbolhound.com/?q=powershell%20-and).  If you use [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/), you can search SymbolHound via `!sym`.

Comment: **2019 update**: I have added this as a feature request to Powershell: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8570

Comment: Vote here: [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3241) and here: [UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087898-implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has)

Comment: **June 2019 update**: PowerShell team are implementing `&&` and `||`! Weigh in at the [GitHub PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/9849)

Comment: @pilau *technically*, a member has opened an RFC with an attached PR, so this isn't strictly committing them to adding it. But it seems pretty unlikely it wont 

Comment: From PowerShell 7, `&&` and `||` are implemented. They are called "pipeline chain operators". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 319, accepted):

In CMD, '&&' means "execute command 1, and if it succeeds, execute command 2".  I have used it for things like:

```
build && run_tests
```

In PowerShell, the closest thing you can do is:

```
(build) -and (run_tests)
```

It has the same logic, but the output text from the commands is lost.  Maybe it is good enough for you, though.

If you're doing this in a script, you will probably be better off separating the statements, like this:

```
build
if ($?) {
    run_tests
}
```

**2019/11/27**: The `&&`operator is now available for [PowerShell 7 Preview 5+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell):

```
PS > echo "Hello!" && echo "World!"
Hello!
World!
```

Comment: I hadn't surrounded the actions with brackets. Once I did that, it worked (but unfortunately just echoed True when it was finished). It seems rather ridiculous that they would remove (well, cripple) such basic functionality

Comment: I don't know much about powershell other than it is based on .NET objects - would it be possible to extend it to add a proper &&, or does the syntax not allow that?

Comment: I don't know of a way to create something like '&&' in PowerShell. You could create a command that takes two scriptblocks, like `andand { build } { run_tests } and does the 'if ($?)' thing with them.  I don't see that as being worth my while, but maybe you will like it.

Comment: RE: "ridiculous that they would remove" - I don't like to think of PowerShell as "CMD with the stupid parts removed".  http://is.gd/k92B

Comment: If you ask the PowerShell team, they'll say "To is to choose", I bet.

Comment: I don't like to think of PowerShell as "CMD with the stupid parts removed". I like to think of it as "Bash without any of the useful bits".

Comment: Even adding the parens it doesn't act as a short cutting conditional logic and operator, it still runs both commands even if the first returns false...

Comment: @joshperry: that doesn't match my experience. I just repeated a simple test `($false) -and (x)` vs. `($true) -and (x)`. One reports an error, one does not.

Comment: You can also do `build ; if ($?) { run_tests }` on the command line too.

Comment: I separated commands by ";" instead of "-and" and the output gets not lost as stated in a comment above.

Comment: `(build) -And (run_tests)` seems to hide the text output of `build` whereas `build ; if ($?) { run_tests }` does not which is preferable. Your mileage may vary

Comment: The quickest way to real frustration when learning PowerShell is to start by thinking that it is just an expanded CMD or bash.  It has a fundamentally different model, *epecially* when it comes to input, output, piping, and results.  Start with a good tutorial or overview, and don't try too hard to make syntax from other shells work. You have to take it on its own terms.

Comment: Taking PowerShell on its own terms, how do I run a command and then, only if that command succeeds, run another command? I don't think that's imposing `bash` ideas on PowerShell. It's basic shell functionality. So far the best I've seen is `build ; if ($?) { run_tests }` which I'll be using from now on. I hope the PowerShell team adds `&&` support!

Comment: `(foo) -and (bar)` does not work functionally the same as `foo; if($?) { bar }`. The former captures stdout of both commands until they end, while latter works as expected, where you get stdout as it comes in

Comment: How can I make ps7 the default when executing `ps <command>` from cmd?

Answer (score 32):

`&&` and `||` were on the list of things to implement (still are) but did not pop up as the next most useful thing to add. The reason is that we have `-AND` and `-OR`.

If you think it is important, please file a suggestion on Connect and we'll consider it for V3.

Comment: I'm signed up on Connect, and have nominated myself for powershell, but I can't figure out how to place a suggestion. The Connect website is really complex and confusing :-(

Comment: I couldn't find a pre-existing request so I made one: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/778798/implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has

Comment: You know, the question is still how to write an equivalent, and your answer would be a lot more useful if you added an example of *using* `-AND`

Comment: It's important because it's a basic flow control tool used on systems older than windows for almost eternity. Thus is presents YET ANOTHER breaking difference between linux and windows.

Comment: @AndyArismendi: Great idea; it seems that your suggestion is now duplicated on [Windows Server User Voice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087898-implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has), which, I presume, supersedes the original (do tell me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I hope Jeffrey Snover is listening, this SO should be enough reason to implement it by now. It's been too long, and now PowerShell starts to popup  in places, like VSCode uses it as a default terminal in Windows. This is total pain without &&, the `-and` eats the output, not equivalent at all.

Comment: "Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired", is there a new place to request this?

Comment: Is it because microsoft is keen on reinventing the wheel in their own backwards way? `(cmd1) -and (cmd2)` is a terrible alternative, because it mutes STDOUT for both processes.

Comment: How did this manage to get 42 upvotes? Instead of attempting to answer the question, it tells people to go file a ticket.

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
$errorActionPreference='Stop'; csc /t:exe /out:a.exe SomeFile.cs; a.exe
```

Comment: Note: If the first command fails the second is still going to run.

Comment: Preference variable `$ErrorActionPreference` only governs how non-terminating errors reported by _cmdlets_ are treated; external utilities such as `csc` and `a.exe` never report such errors (they only reflect their exit status in `$?` (success flag) and `$LASTEXITCODE` (the specific exit code reported)), so your command line amounts to _unconditional_ execution of _both_ commands (the equivalent of `cmd`'s `csc /t:exe /out:a.exe SomeFile.cs & a.exe`)

Comment: But this command does preserve command output.

Answer (score 21):

If your command is available in cmd.exe (something like `python ./script.py`, but not PowerShell command like `ii .` (this means to open the current directory by [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer))), you can run cmd.exe within PowerShell. The syntax is like this:

```
cmd /c "command1 && command2"
```

Here, `&&` is provided by cmd syntax described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719174/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-line).

Comment: Thanks!! This is definitely the best answer because the result is as close as possible as if you were using CMD natively. 

For me it worked perfectly, I needed to use with Gitlab-Runner on Windows, where CMD support is deprecated now... as PowerShell doesn't have the same behavior to chain commands with && or || I really MUST use the CMD "inside" Powershell, something like: 

`PS C:\Users\myusername> cmd /c "where ssh-agent || echo Need to install OpenSSH or GIT on this Runner"`

Comment: **Quick Tip:** With Powershell if you need to use the `where` command for the same result as you get in CMD, you can't just use `where`, you need to use `where.exe` (with the extension), because without the extension Powershell uses an alias to its own version of the `where` command.

Answer (score 8):

### I tried this sequence of commands in PowerShell:

#### First Test

```
PS C:\> $MyVar = "C:\MyTxt.txt"
PS C:\> ($MyVar -ne $null) -and (Get-Content $MyVar)
True
```

`($MyVar -ne $null)` returned **true** and `(Get-Content $MyVar)` also returned **true**.

#### Second Test

```
PS C:\> $MyVar = $null
PS C:\> ($MyVar -ne $null) -and (Get-Content $MyVar)
False
```

`($MyVar -ne $null)` returned **false** and so far I must assume the `(Get-Content $MyVar)` also returned **false**.

#### The third test proved the second condition was not even analyzed.

```
PS C:\> ($MyVar -ne $null) -and (Get-Content "C:\MyTxt.txt")
False
```

`($MyVar -ne $null)` returned **false** and proved the second condition `(Get-Content "C:\MyTxt.txt")` never ran, by returning **false** on the whole command.

Comment: Your are right! this behaves as the && operator. Even a $() on the right side will not let to evaluate this!

Answer (score 4):

Very old question, but for the newcomers: maybe the PowerShell version (similar but *not equivalent*) that the question is looking for, is to use `-and` as follows:

`(build_command) -and (run_tests_command)`

Comment: This may be ok for your use case, but it is not behaving like `&&`, in that it ignores the exit code of `build_command`.

Comment: This is definitely not doing the correct thing. It will run the second command even if the first one failed.

Comment: this is completely wrong. `;` is the equivalent to `&` in cmd and `;` in bash. It's definitely not the same as `&&` in cmd

Comment: It also mutes STDOUT and STDERR for both processes.

Comment: After numerous edits this duplicates the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/564092/389424

Answer (score 4):

Just install PowerShell 7 ([go here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases), and scroll and expand the assets section). [This release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7) has implemented the pipeline chain operators.

Answer (score 3):

A verbose equivalent is to combine `$LASTEXITCODE` and `-eq 0`:

```
msbuild.exe args; if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { echo 'it built'; } else { echo 'it failed'; }
```

I'm not sure why `if ($?)` didn't work for me, but this one did.

Comment: Checking `$LASTEXITCODE` is indeed the most robust approach, because, unfortunately, `$?` can yield false negatives with `2>` redirections; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623532/45375).

Answer (score 1):

I also have faced the same issue. The cause is that I am using an old version of powershell (I am already on Windows 11). To check version type this in powershell: `$PSVersionTable`

I found I was actually using version 5, while the latest is 7.4.

```
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.963
PSEdition                      Desktop
```

After install the latest (you can download separately or just go Microsoft Store), And ensure you have successfully switched to new version (you may need to extra config to choose this version, as it install new version not replacing old one)

```
PSVersion                      7.3.2
PSEdition                      Core
```

After I switch to the latest version, `&&` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

in 2023, you can use `;` operator in PowerShell.

`&&` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `;` has always worked. It operates fundamentally differently than the concept of `&&`. As the OP mentioned in the question, `&&` guarantees that former commands need to complete successfully for the latter commands to even be ran. Separating them with a `;` does not have this same guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (start-process filename1.exe) {} else {start-process filename2.exe}
```

It's a little longer than "&&", but it accomplishes the same thing without scripting and is not too hard to remember.

Comment: `Start-Process` is the wrong tool to use for invoking command-line utilities in general. Specifically, as used here, `Start-Process` runs `filename1.exe` asynchronously in a new console window and returns _nothing_, which in a Boolean context evaluates to `$false`. Even if you omitted `Start-Process` (which is how you should invoke command-line utilities - directly), the approach would fall short, because the outcome of the conditional then depends on whether the utility produced any stdout output, which has no guaranteed relationship with whether it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `if` statement can accomplish this. Once I saw mkelement0's response that the last exit status is stored in $?, I put the following together:

```
# Set the first command to a variable
$a=somecommand

# Temporary variable to store exit status of the last command (since we can't write to "$?")
$test=$?

# Run the test
if ($test=$true) { 2nd-command }
```

So for the OP's example, it would be:

```
a=(csc /t:exe /out:a.exe SomeFile.cs); $test = $?; if ($test=$true) { a.exe }
```

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the context, but here's an example of "-and" in action:

```
get-childitem | where-object { $_.Name.StartsWith("f") -and $_.Length -gt 10kb }
```

So that's getting all the files bigger than 10kb in a directory whose filename starts with "f".

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, which is about executing multiple commands.

Answer (score -2):

We can try this command instead of using && method:

```
try {hostname; if ($lastexitcode -eq 0) {ipconfig /all | findstr /i bios}} catch {echo err} finally {}
```

Comment: There is no need for `try` / `catch`, because it is only needed for _terminating_ errors, which external utilities such as `hostname`, `ipconfig` and `findstr` cannot trigger. Checking `$LASTEXITCODE` is only needed if you want to know the specific exit code set by an external utility - abstract success or failure is reflected in `$?`, just as with native cmdlets.

Comment: I think @Cyberiron is on the right track. I think `&&` in Unix is a lot like try/catch in that it doesn't require you to wrap subsequent commands in a new block (i.e. `}`) when you short-circuit later commands (skip them).  I think a `AmpAmp` function/filter that throws when `if (!?) { throw "last command failed" }` would be a very useful replacement for porting `&&` to PowerShell.
**usage**: ``csc /t:exe /out:a.exe SomeFile.cs; AmpAmp; a.exe``