# conditional execution (&& and ||) in powershell

Tags: syntax, powershell, command-execution

There's already question addressing my issue ([Can I get && to work in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563600/can-i-get-to-work-in-powershell)), but with one difference. I need an **OUTPUT** from both commands. See, if I just run:

```
(command1 -arg1 -arg2) -and (command2 -arg1)
```

I won't see any output, but stderr messages. And, as expected, just typing:

```
command1 -arg1 -arg2 -and command2 -arg1
```

Gives syntax error.

Comment: A short-ciruiting OR will only execute the second expression if the first evals to false (fails).  I suspect the OP wants the second expression to execute only if the first evals to true (succeeds) which a short-circuiting -and gives us.

Comment: Whoever is interested in Bash-style `&&` and `||` becoming a part of PowerShell: please vote for the feature [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087898-implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the PowerShell equivalent of Bash's && and || operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416662/what-are-the-powershell-equivalent-of-bashs-and-operators)

Comment: Note: Despite this question's tile mentioning both `&&` and `||`, the body - and subsequently the answers - focus on `&&` only. A [closely related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2416662/45375) is more generic.

Comment: **June 2019 update**: PowerShell team are implementing `&&` and `||`! Weigh in at the [GitHub PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/9849)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**2019**: the Powershell team are [considering adding support for `&&` to Powershell - weigh in at this GitHub PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/9849)

Try this:

```
$(command -arg1 -arg2 | Out-Host;$?) -and $(command2 -arg1 | Out-Host;$?)
```

The `$()` is a subexpression allowing you to specify multiple statements within including a pipeline.  Then execute the command and pipe to `Out-Host` so you can see it.  The next statement (the actual output of the subexpression) should output `$?` i.e. the last command's success result.

---

The `$?` works fine for native commands (console exe's) but for cmdlets it leaves something to be desired.  That is, `$?` only seems to return `$false` when a cmdlet encounters a terminating error.  Seems like `$?` needs at least three states (failed, succeeded and partially succeeded). So if you're using cmdlets, this works better:

```
$(command -arg1 -arg2 -ev err | Out-Host;!$err) -and 
$(command -arg1 -ev err | Out-Host;!$err)
```

This kind of blows still. Perhaps something like this would be better:

```
function ExecuteUntilError([scriptblock[]]$Scriptblock)
{
    foreach ($sb in $scriptblock)
    {
        $prevErr = $error[0]
        . $sb
        if ($error[0] -ne $prevErr) { break }
    }
}

ExecuteUntilError {command -arg1 -arg2},{command2-arg1}
```

Comment: Thanks, Keith (BTW, I use PSCX and find it great, many thanks for those!). Though it seems pretty usable, there's a drawback comparing to UNIX pipeline. Consider the following: `command1 && command2 || command3`. It's pretty common pattern, I think.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit of a hack compared to proper && and || support.

Comment: Since (at least) PSv2, _non-terminating_ errors _do_ set `$?` to `$false`: for instance, `$null = Get-Item \, nosuch; $?` outputs `$false`.
In the case of a _terminating_ error, the command line / script would abort altogether by default; if you do `try` / `catch` the error, `$?` is `$false` in the `catch` block, or, if the `catch` block is empty, immediately afterward; e.g., `try { throw "terminating err" } catch { }; $?`

Comment: The `ExecuteUntilError` function is handy, but please make it more obvious how much of a hack the `Out-Host` solution is, given that it bypasses the normal success output stream and therefore prevents sending the output through the pipeline or capturing it in a variable or file.

Comment: To paraphrase your statement about the need for 3 `$?` states: With cmdlets, `$?` allows you to distinguish only between "processing of all input items succeeded" and "processing of at least one, but possibly all input items failed"; in other words: you cannot distinguish between partial and complete failure; the workaround is to compare the input count to the change in `$Error.Count`.

Answer (score 7):

Powershell 7 preview 5 has them. 
 I don't know why this was deleted with no notification or explanation.
 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-7-preview-5/  This will give the output of both commands, as the question requested.

```
echo 'hello' && echo 'there'
hello
there

echo 'hello' || echo 'there'
hello
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you are using powershell seriously, use the powershell-preview chocolatey package.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify multistep scripts where *doThis || exit 1* would be really useful, I use something like:

```
function ProceedOrExit { 
    if ($?) { echo "Proceed.." } else { echo "Script FAILED! Exiting.."; exit 1 } 
}

doThis; ProceedOrExit
doNext

# or for long doos
doThis
ProceedOrExit
doNext
```

Answer (score 3):

*Update*: **PowerShell [Core] 7.0 introduced `&&` and `||` support** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59039112/45375).

---

**Bash's / `cmd`'s `&&` and `||` control operators have NO Windows PowerShell equivalents**, and since you cannot define custom operators, there are **no good workarounds**.

- The `| Out-Host`-based workaround in [Keith Hill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2252734/45375) is a severely limited in that it can only send normal command output to the *console* (terminal), preventing the output from being sent on through the pipeline or being captured in a variable or file.

Find background information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Little longer way is see below

```
try {
  hostname
  if ($lastexitcode -eq 0) {
    ipconfig /all | findstr /i bios
  }
} catch {
  echo err
} finally {}
```

Comment: There is no need for `try` / `catch`, because it is only needed for _terminating_ errors, which external utilities such as `hostname`, `ipconfig` and `findstr` cannot trigger. Checking `$LASTEXITCODE` is only needed if you want to know the specific exit code set by an external utility - abstract success or failure is reflected in `$?`, just as with native cmdlets. As an aside: please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use

```
powershell command1 && powershell command2
```

in a cmd shell.  Of course, you can't use this in a .ps1 script, so there's that limitation.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, correct, but the `&&` here isn't in powershell, it's in a cmd shell.  My answer here is to use cmd to string together 2 powershell commands (both with full output printed).

Answer (score 1):

With Powershell 7.0 released, `&&` and `||` are supported

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-powershell-7-0/

```
New operators:
  Ternary operator: a ? b : c
  Pipeline chain operators: || and &&
  Null coalescing operators: ?? and ??=
```