# What are the PowerShell equivalents of Bash's && and || operators?

Tags: bash, powershell, language-comparisons

In Bash I can easily do something like

```
command1 && command2 || command3
```

which means to run command1 and if command1 succeeds to run command2 and if command1 fails to run command3.

What's the equivalent in PowerShell?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next ?

Comment: Stej, you did - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251622/conditional-execution-and-in-powershell

Comment: Interesting method to write your own [over on superuser](http://superuser.com/a/764639/114388).

Comment: **June 2019 update**: PowerShell team are implementing `&&` and `||`! Weigh in at the [GitHub PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/9849)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What Bash must be doing is interpreting the integer exit code of the commands as true or false when passed to the logical operators.  PowerShell doesn't do this - but a function can be made to wrap the command and create the same behavior:

```
> function Get-ExitBoolean($cmd) { & $cmd | Out-Null; $? }
```

([$? is a bool containing the success of the last exit code](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/09/15/ErrorLevel-equivalent.aspx))

Given two batch files:

```
#pass.cmd
exit
```

and

```
#fail.cmd
exit /b 200
```

...the behavior can be tested:

```
> if (Get-ExitBoolean .\pass.cmd) { write pass } else { write fail }
pass
> if (Get-ExitBoolean .\fail.cmd) { write pass } else { write fail }
fail
```

The logical operators should be evaluated the same way as in Bash.  First, set an alias:

```
> Set-Alias geb Get-ExitBoolean
```

Test:

```
> (geb .\pass.cmd) -and (geb .\fail.cmd)
False
> (geb .\fail.cmd) -and (geb .\pass.cmd)
False
> (geb .\pass.cmd) -and (geb .\pass.cmd)
True
> (geb .\pass.cmd) -or (geb .\fail.cmd)
True
```

Comment: So there is no simple built-in functionality for this?

Comment: No, don't think so.  I believe the designers did their best to avoid operator-hijacking usage like that.  In fact, there's no ternary operator either.  It is powerful enough, however, to provide the means to easily roll your own.  http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/12/29/dyi-ternary-operator.aspx

Comment: Not sure the `| Out-Null` is necessarily a good idea. Maybe pipe to `Write-Host` so we can still see the output?

Comment: @JamesKolpack: The only reason for the absence of both `&&` / `||` and the ternary conditional operator from the language is that _they never made it to the top of the list - both have been acknowledged as potentially useful additions_: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/573295/45375) for `&&` / `||`, and, with respect to the ternary operator, the very article you link to starts with "One of the things we were very disappointed in not being able to ship in V1.0 is a ternary operator."

Comment: To be clear, `Get-ExitCodeBoolean()` is _not_ a generic replacement for `&&` / `||`, because it _suppresses regular output_, preventing its capture in a variable / file / sending it through a pipeline. The beauty of Bash's `&&` / `||` control operators is that _they don't interfere with the output streams and only act on the (invisible) exit codes_ - and that cannot (currently) be done in PowerShell. If you think it should, [vote for it here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087898-implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has).

Comment: "What Bash must be doing is implicitly casting the exit code of the commands to a Boolean when passed to the logical operators."  Definitely no, if for no other reason than bash only knows strings and 32 bit integers.

Comment: @RonJohn - thanks, it's definitely not worded correctly, I removed the "casting" bit and talked about Bash interpreting the integers as true or false when doing logical operations.

Comment: @JamesKolpack that’s not true either.  **Success** == 0, while **failure** >= 0.

Answer (score 62):

*Update*: **`&&` and `||` have finally come to [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, namely in **v7+**, termed [*pipeline-chain operators*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59039112/45375) for details.

---

Many years after the question was first asked, let me summarize **the behavior of *Windows PowerShell*, whose latest and *final* version is v5.1**:

- **Bash's / `cmd`'s `&&` and `||` control operators have NO PowerShell equivalents**, and since you cannot define custom operators in PowerShell, there are **no good workarounds**:

  - Use **separate commands** (on separate lines or separated with `;`), and explicitly test the success status of each command via [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1), e.g.:

    ```
    # Equivalent of &&
    command1 -arg1 -arg2; if ($?) { command2 -arg1 }

    # Equivalent of ||
    command1 -arg1 -arg2; if (-not $?) { command2 -arg1 }
    ```
  - **Better alternative for *external programs***, using the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode); this is preferable, because `$?` in Windows PowerShell can yield *false negatives* (no longer in PowerShell (Core) 7.2+), if a `2>` redirection is involved - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623532/45375):

    ```
    # Equivalent of &&
    command1 -arg1 -arg2; if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { command2 -arg1 }

    # Equivalent of ||
    command1 -arg1 -arg2; if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { command2 -arg1 }
    ```
  - See below for why PowerShell's `-and` and `-or` are generally *not* a solution.
- [*Since implemented in PowerShell (Core) 7+*] There was [talk about adding them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573295/45375) a while back, but it seemingly never made the top of the list.

  - Now that PowerShell has gone open-source, an [issue has been opened on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3241).
  - The tokens `&&` and `||` are currently reserved for future use in PowerShell, so there's hope that the same syntax as in Bash can be implemented.
    (As of PSv5.1, attempting something like `1 && 1` yields error message `The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.`)

---

#### Why PowerShell's `-and` and `-or` are no substitute for `&&` and `||`:

**Bash**'s control operators `&&` (short-circuiting logical AND) and `||` (short-circuiting logical OR) implicitly **check the success status of commands by their exit codes, *without interfering with their output streams***; e.g.:

```
ls / nosuchfile && echo 'ok'
```

Whatever `ls` outputs -- both stdout output (the files in `/`) and stderr output (the error message from attempting to access non-existent file `nosuchfile`) -- is *passed through*, but `&&` checks the (invisible) *exit code* of the `ls` command to decide if the `echo` command - the RHS of the `&&` control operator - should be executed.

`ls` reports exit code `1` in this case, signaling *failure* -- because file `nosuchfile` doesn't exist -- so `&&` decides that `ls` *failed* and, by applying short-circuiting, decides that the `echo` command need not be executed.
Note that it is exit code `0` that signals success in the world of `cmd.exe` and `bash`, whereas any *nonzero* exit code indicates failure.

In other words: **Bash's `&&` and `||` operate completely independently of the commands' *output* and only act on the *success status* of the commands.**

---

**PowerShell's `-and` and `-or`, by contrast, act only on the commands' standard (success) *output*, *consume* it** and then **output only the Boolean result of the operation**; e.g.:

```
(Get-ChildItem \, nosuchfile) -and 'ok'
```

The above:

- uses *and consumes* the *success* (standard) output -- the listing of `\` -- and interprets it as a *Boolean*; a non-empty input collection is considered `$true` in a Boolean context, so if there's at least one entry, the expression evaluates to `$true`.

  - However, the *error* information resulting from nonexistent file `nosuchfile` *is* passed through, because errors are sent to a separate stream.
- Given that `Get-ChildItem \, nosuchfile` returns non-empty success output, the LHS evaluated to `$true`, so `-and` also evaluates the RHS, `'ok'`, but, again, *consumes* its output and interprets it as a Boolean, which, as a nonempty string, also evaluates to `$true`.
- Thus, the overall result of the `-and` expression is `$true`, which is (the only success) *output*.

The **net effect** is:

- The **success output** from both sides of the `-and` expression is *consumed* during evaluation and therefore **effectively *hidden***.
- **The expression's only (success) output is its Boolean result**, which is `$true` in this case (which renders as `True` in the terminal).

Comment: Huge hack, but I need an inline call and couldn't add functions. So I ended up with this: `command1 ; $? -or (command3)`

Comment: Interesting, @PedroWitzel; that would still output a Boolean, however, while suppressing `command3`'s stdout output; to get closer to Bash's behavior, you'd need something like `command1; $null = $? -or ($output = command3); $output`, but that would print stderr output before stdout.

Comment: Are the first two code examples switched? Wouldn't `command1 -arg1 -arg2; if ($?) { command2 -arg1 }` be the equivalent of `||`?

Comment: No, @xdhmoore: `$?` is a _Boolean_ in PowerShell.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this, where you hide the boolean output with [void], and only get the side effect.  In this case, if $a or $b are null, then $c gets assigned to $result.  An assignment can be an expression.

```
$a = ''
$b = ''
$c = 'hi'

[void](
  ($result = $a) -or
  ($result = $b) -or
  ($result = $c))

$result
```

output

```
hi
```

Comment: You can't derive a command's success vs. failure from its _output_, so this no substitute for `&&` and `||`. What if a command succeeds and either produces no output at all or happens to output something that is falsy, e.g. `0`?

Answer (score -3):

We can use try catch finally method instead of using && method in powershell.

```
try {hostname} catch {echo err} finally {ipconfig /all | findstr bios}
```

Comment: `try` / `catch` is pointless here, because it is only needed for _terminating_ errors, which an external utility such as `hostname` cannot trigger. Your code will _unconditionally_ execute _both_ commands.