# How to perform short-circuit evaluation in Windows PowerShell 4.0?

Tags: c#, vb.net, powershell, short-circuiting

Technet's ***[about_Logical_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx)*** with respect to **Windows PowerShell 4.0** states the following:

```
Operator     Description                        Example

--------     ------------------------------     ------------------------
-or          Logical or. TRUE when either       (1 -eq 1) -or (1 -eq 2) 
             or both statements are TRUE.       True

-xor         Logical exclusive or. TRUE         (1 -eq 1) -xor (2 -eq 2)
             only when one of the statements    False 
             is TRUE and the other is FALSE.
```

Neither seem to perform short-circuit evaluation.

How can I mimic the **C#** `||` or **VB** `OrElse` in **Windows Powershell 4.0**?

Comment: You didn't read past that, did you ;) Later in the document you refer to: "The Windows PowerShell logical operators evaluate only the statements required to determine the truth value of the statement..."

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I did actually, but I was confused by the description of the `-or` operator.  [Keith Hill's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26768902/682480) shows that it does short-circuit by default and helped clear things up for me.

Comment: logically (ahem, pun acknowledged), `-xor` could not possibly short circuit... right? It must evaluate both sides of the expression to determine the exclusivity... ... right?

Comment: @CodeJockey sounds right.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A simple set of test cases show that short-circuiting works:

```
PS C:\> 1 -eq 0 -or $(Write-Host 'foo')
foo
False
PS C:\> 1 -eq 1 -or $(Write-Host 'foo')
True

PS C:\> 1 -eq 1 -and $(Write-Host 'foo')
foo
False
PS C:\> 1 -eq 0 -and $(Write-Host 'foo')
False
```

Comment: Very interesting. I was wondering if `-or` did that by default, but the documentation stated otherwise.  But now, after re-reading the description, it does say `when either or both`, so I guess that would mean that it does some form of short-circuiting by default.

Comment: Yes it does short-circuiting by default for the -and & -or operators.

Comment: [But it is not the short circuiting that has been around in *nix shells for decades.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/711422)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same, came across this answer. The best so far in my opinion...

```
$cueNumber = 512
@{ $true = "This is true"; $false = "This is false" }[$cueNumber -gt 500]
```

Reference: https://adamtheautomator.com/a-simpler-ifthen-conditional-logic-in-powershell/