# ConvertTo-Html with null input

Tags: powershell

The following script will feed `ConvertTo-Html` with `$null` value.

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance xxxx "select top 0 1 A -- returns no row" |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

It will generate the following html code. Is there a simple way (without introducing variable and if statement) to not generate the empty `<table>` but a text message if the input is null?

```
<table>
</table>
```

Or is there a way to let `Invoke-SqlCmd` return a string if empty?

Comment: `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment` is doing what it is being told to do. Wrap `$null` in a table. Don't think you can change this behavior. What no `if`? You are asking to react to the null so a condition has to be established. You could also check the output to see if it matches `<table></table>`

Comment: Not possible without an `if` statement because of the absence of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416662/what-are-the-powershell-equivalent-of-bashs-and-operators), which would work in bourne shell

Answer (score 0):

Don't *think* there is a way to get what you are asking for within the restricting criteria you are providing. The behaviour you are trying to prevent/account for is this

```
$null | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
<table>
</table>
```

`$null` is something *tangible* that `ConvertTo-Html` is wrapping with table tags. If you want to react to this that requires some conditional statement.

```
 $table =  $null | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
 If([string]$table -eq "<table> </table>"){Write-Host "Table is empty" -ForegroundColor Red}
```