# Is there a powershell pattern for if($?) { }

Tags: powershell, error-handling, syntax

I find myself chaining these a lot, eg:

```
do-cmd-one
if($?)
{
do-cmd-two
}
...
```

then at the end:

```
if(!$?)
{
   exit 1
}
```

I assume there's a pattern for this in powershell but I don't know it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**PowerShell (Core) 7.0** introduced **Bash-like `&&` and `||` operators called [*pipeline-chain operators*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators)**.

<sup>They will *not* be back-ported to *Windows PowerShell*, however, as the latter will generally see no new features.</sup>

In short, **instead of**:

```sh
do-cmd-one; if ($?) { do-cmd-two }
```

<sup>Note: Up to PowerShell 7.1, the more robust formulation is actually

`do-cmd-one; if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { do-cmd-two }`, for the reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623532/45375).</sup>

**you can now write**:

```sh
do-cmd-one && do-cmd-two
```

**`&&` (AND) and `||` (OR) implicitly operate on each command's *implied success status*, as reflected in automatic Boolean variable `$?`**.

This will likely be **more useful with *external programs***, whose exit codes unambiguously imply whether `$?` is `$true` (exit code `0`) or `$false` (any nonzero exit code).

By contrast, for PowerShell commands (cmdlets) `$?` just reflects whether the command failed as a whole (a *statement-terminating* error occurred) or whether at least one *non-terminating* error was reported; the latter doesn't necessarily indicate overall failure.
However, [there are plans to allow PowerShell commands to set `$?` directly](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917#issuecomment-550550490), as a deliberate overall-success indicator.

Also note that **the following do *not* work with `&&` and `||`**:

- **PowerShell's `Test-*` cmdlets**, because they signal the test result by *outputting* a *Boolean* rather than by setting `$?`; e.g., 
  `Test-Path $somePath || Write-Warning "File missing"` wouldn't work.
- **Boolean *expressions***, for the same reason; e.g., 
  `$files.Count -gt 0 || write-warning 'No files found'` wouldn't work.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/45375) for background information, and the discussion in [GitHub issue #10917](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917).

---

There's a **syntax caveat**: As of this writing, the following will *not* work:

```sh
do-cmd-one || exit 1 # !! Currently does NOT work
```

Instead, **you're forced to wrap `exit` / `return` / `throw` statements in `$(...)`**, the so-called subexpression operator:

```sh
do-cmd-one || $(exit 1) # Note the need for $(...)
```

[GitHub issue #10967](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10967) discusses the reasons for this awkward requirement, which are rooted in the fundamentals of PowerShell's grammar.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you like this any better.

```
if($(do-cmd-one; $?))
{
  do-cmd-two
}
else
{
   exit 1
}
```

Some other ideas.  If actually doesn't check the exit code of a command.  But if a command has no output when failing, and has output when successful, it can work.  In this case, I'm hiding the error messages.  If will always hide a command's regular output.

```
if(test-connection -Count 1 microsoft.com 2>$null) { 'yes' } # never responds
if(test-connection -Count 1 yahoo.com 2>$null) { 'yes' }
yes
```

Test-connection happens to have a quiet option that returns a boolean anyway:

```
if(test-connection -count 1 yahoo.com -quiet) { 'yes' }
yes
if(test-connection -count 1 microsoft.com -quiet) { 'yes' }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's still pretty awkward.

Comment: This isn't functionally equivalent, because it effectively discards the command's stdout / success-stream output. It would also yield false positives if `do-cmd-one` produced such output while reporting `$false` via `$?`.

Comment: @mklement0 The question doesn't give an example of using the command output.  But it is possible to get a false positive, if the command both gave an output, and also had an exception, like `dir foo,foo2` where foo existed but foo2 didn't.

Comment: The code in the question calls the commands without redirecting or capturing the commands' output. Your answer discards the first command's output without even mentioning that fact. The false positives could be avoided with `$null = do-cmd-one`, but the differing output behavior would remain.