# The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powershell, webpack

On the way of installing **Webpack** on my React Project, the following problem hinders my progress:

**last step to configure the Webpack**

```
npm run build && node ./dist/main.js
```

**Error on Windows Power Shell / on Visual Studio Code**

```
PS C:\Users\pythonbuddha\Desktop\to_experiment\to-do-list> npm run build && node ./dist/main.js
At line:1 char:15
+ npm run build && node ./dist/main.js
+               ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

**Tutorial which promised to configure the webpack**

```
https://developerhandbook.com/webpack/webpack-4-from-absolute-scratch/

https://developerhandbook.com/webpack/how-to-configure-scss-modules-for-webpack/
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It's because you're in PowerShell, try running it in `CMD` or [`Git Bash`](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

Alternatively (if you wish to continue in PS):

```
(npm run build) -and (node ./dist/main.js)
```

3rd Alternative, just run them separetly,

Comment: it worked for command line issue but created issue related to React.

Comment: Good point about a different command being needed in Windows PowerShell (though no longer in PowerShell (Core) 7+), but it is important to note that PowerShell's `-and` and `-or` operators are _not_ replacements for `&&` and `||` - they function fundamentally differently, effectively discarding stdout output and returning a single Boolean instead - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/45375).

Comment: I'd argue that mentioning the `-and` alternative is a bit misleading as I doubt people would normally want what `-and` does (I certainly did not want that and only realised this when my command was running). The answer should just mention that to achieve the same in Powershell use PowerShell version 7+.

Comment: Good point. It solved my issue. I was trying on the terminal.

Answer (score 66):

I found that within PowerShell as my terminal within `VS Code`, replacing `&&` in the command with `;` did the trick.

Comment: `;` is the statement separator in PowerShell, resulting in _unconditional_ sequencing of commands, analogous to `&` in `cmd.exe` - this is _not_ the same as `&&`, which only executes the RHS command _if the LHS command succeeded_.

Comment: tested, yes works fine. 

Eg:
``` 
git add --all ; git commit -m 'testing' ; git push
```

Comment: @LeoLanese it "works" if you did not encounter any error in the execution chain, what the OP has been referring to is `conditional execution`, `&&` is normally use for command chains that can only continue execution when the previous was successful, 

here is a bad practice example for working in a write restricted location, `md "C:\Program Files\test"; cd "C:\Program Files\test"; git init`,  it will `git init` on your current directory instead, it could be worse...

@mklement0's answer is the most appropriate, and it is still a valid issue/workaround when we use vanilla Windows 10's PS

Answer (score 29):

**[PowerShell (Core) v7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)  - but *not* *Windows PowerShell* - now *does* support `&&` and `||`**, the [pipeline-chain  operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators), so **your command should work as-is there** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59039112/45375) for PowerShell-specific considerations for their use; see below for Windows PowerShell workarounds.

**Conceptual note:**

- In all shells that support it (notably `cmd.exe` and POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash), **`&&` *conditionally* sequences commands: it executes its RHS command only if the LHS command indicated *success***; `||` is the inverse: it executes the RHS only if the LHS indicated *failure*.
- This is important for preventing execution when it makes no sense to do so; e.g., in 
  `npm run build && node ./dist/main.js` it only makes sense to run what was just built (with `node`) *if the build succeeded*, which is what `&&` ensures.

***Windows PowerShell* workarounds:**

The **most *succinct*** workaround:

```
npm run build; if ($?) { node ./dist/main.js }
```

This builds on the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1), which is a Boolean indicating whether the most recent command succeeded.

The **most *robust*** workaround, needed **if the commands use `2>` redirections**:

```
npm run build; if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { node ./dist/main.js }
```

Basing the success test on the [automatic `$LastExitCode` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), which reflects the *process exit code* of the most recently executed *external program*, avoids problems in Windows PowerShell<sup>[1]</sup> where the presence of *stderr* output in combination with redirecting it via `2>` mistakenly sets `$?` to `$false` even when the process exit code is `0`.

---

<sup>[1] The problems with `2>` redirections are summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726535/45375). They also plague PowerShell (Core) up to version 7.1</sup>

Comment: I installed the new powershell. How do I make it the default when executing `ps <command>` from cmd?

Comment: @Qwerty, PowerShell (Core)'s executable is `pwsh.exe` (whereas Windows PowerShell's is `powershell.exe`).

Answer (score 9):

The `&&` operator is used in linux `bash` to run both commands after each other. (Also if the first command fails, the second won't be executed)

This does not work in PowerShell on Windows so just split both commands and run them separately:

```
npm run build
node ./dist/main.js
```

---

For completeness, Powershell can behave the same when you do `(command1) -and (command2)` and `&&` might actually work depending on your PowerShell version.

See this for further info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/564092/2232127

Comment: Running two commands in sequence _unconditionally_  (which you can do on the same line by using statement separator `;` in PowerShell) is _not_ the same as the `&&` operator. `-and` and `-or` in PowerShell work fundamentally differently and will more likely than not _not_ work as intended, as I've tried to show in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/45375).

Comment: I missed that your opening paragraph correctly describes `&&`. I suggest making it clearer that your PowerShell solution _acts differently_ - but note that a Windows PowerShell emulation of `&&` is readily available (and no longer needed in PowerShell v7+, where `&&` and `||` are now supported).

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by upgrading powershell and renamed dir. path folder name by removing spaces. Now it works properly.

Powershell upgradation link

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell

Comment: Yes, as previously mentioned PowerShell (Core) versions 7.0 and above now support `&&` and `||`. It is unclear how spaces in folder names relate to this. Also, I suggest not using a link to an obsolete preview version of PowerShell. For users currently using the legacy, comes-with-the-OS _Windows PowerShell_ edition, switching to the cross-platform, install-on-demand _PowerShell (Core)_ edition is more than just an upgrade: it requires a very deliberate migration and the awareness that certain existing code may break.

Answer (score 1):

Since some people might arrive here in the same manner as I did, wondering why PowerShell would not allow me to perform a conditional AND operator between two variables within an if statement.

I solved it by evaluating the Left Condition with an If condition, and then the Right Condition immediately within the first true condition.

Example that produced the error:

```
$Path = "C:\\Temp\test"
$RootPath = "C:\\Temp"
$currentChildren = Get-ChildItem -Force -LiteralPath $Path 
$isEmpty = $currentChildren -eq null

if ($isEmpty && $Path -ne $RootPath) {
    Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $Path
    }

$foo = "question"
$bar = "answer"
```

Example that I used to solve the problem:

```
$Path = "C:\\Temp\test"
$RootPath = "C:\\Temp"
$currentChildren = Get-ChildItem -Force -LiteralPath $Path 
$isEmpty = $currentChildren -eq null

if ($isEmpty) {
    if ($Path -ne $RootPath) {
        Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $Path
        }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Having this issue on the Windows terminal. Solution is to use `;` instead `&&` like:

```
git fetch --all ; git add --all ; git commit -m 'updating things' ; git push
```

Answer (score -1):

in the ps terminal for vs code or phpstorm just replace the && with , and hit run
Instead of

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Do

```
npm install; npm run dev
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
npm run build; if ($?) { node ./dist/main.js }
```

Just like the command in cmd:

```
npm run build && node ./dist/main.js
```

Answer (score -1):

this works just fine using Git bash.

just check it out...

Example

user@DevKitchen MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/BL_proxy/portfolio (master)
$ cd src && mkdir content && cd content && touch navbar.js about.js services.js projects.js