# Am trying to run todo app, seem to be getting an error when running yarn

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I just downloaded a React TODO application - https://github.com/mdn/todo-react

I keep getting this error when trying to run: yarn && yarn start

```
At line:1 char:6
+ yarn && yarn start
+      ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

Can anyone help?

Tried running:

yarn && yarn install

expected to get the application running as specified in the build notes:

Getting started
To get this app running locally, you'll need to have Node.js and Yarn installed on your machine. In the project directory, you can run:

yarn && yarn start
More information about the available commands can be found in the Contributing guide.

Comment: Hi @BigSargeNCharge, looks like it is similar to this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627536/the-token-is-not-a-valid-statement-separator-in-this-version

Comment: This looks like a PowerShell issue, you are trying to run a shell command in a PS terminal, try using git bash or cmd. Or simply use PowerShell's command separator `;`: `yarn; yarn install`. Edit: just clicked sakti's link, that should solve your issue.