# PowerShell - How to use && type statement

Tags: windows, powershell, command

Using the command below, I am able to get the value of a group policy setting:

```
secedit.exe /export /cfg C:\test\secedit.txt && type C:\test\secedit.txt | findstr "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege"
```

I need to be able to use the same command on PowerShell and I am having issues converting the && statement to work on PowerShell. I tried using this format **() -and ()**, however, that has not worked, does anyone know a way of getting the && statement to work on PS?

Comment: In short: Only _PowerShell v7+_ supports `&&` and `||`, the pipeline-chaining operators - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59039112/45375). In earlier versions, notably in _Windows PowerShell_, you can emulate `a && b` with `a; if ($?) { b }` and `a || b` with `a; if (-not $?) { b }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/45375)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to emulate what that command is doing in PowerShell just change the `&&` for a `;`:

```
secedit.exe /export /cfg C:\test\secedit.txt; type C:\test\secedit.txt | findstr "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege"
```

I would add `1>$null` after the first command to avoid the output of ***The task has completed successfully.....***

#### Edit

I understand `;` and `&&` or `||` are not the same thing in PS 5.1 and below, but is the closest thing I can imagine to emulate what OP is doing.

Other thing he could attempt is:

```
secedit.exe /export /cfg C:\test\secedit.txt;if($?){type C:\test\secedit.txt | findstr "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege"}
```

I would link [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563600/can-i-get-or-and-to-work-in-powershell) which explains it better than I do.

Comment: Powershell [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1) nowadays pipeline chaining operators `&&` and `||`. Those are not the same as a semicolon?

Comment: @vonPryz Yeah I know PS Core supports `&&` and `||` however OP clearly is not using PS Core or hes command would have worked.

Comment: Thank you guys!! The recommended parameters work well on my version of PS.

Comment: @Help you probably already have but if not, have a read at the answer I posted in my edit. It explains the PS behaviour better than I do.