# How can I ensure a line of PowerShell does not break the script on failure?

Tags: powershell

I have a command `mycommand` that sometimes gives a bad exit code, but I want to continue executing the script. However, I don't want to disable exiting on bad exit codes for the other lines.

On Linux systems I can change the command to `mycommand || true` which will ensure that this line always succeeds. How can I do this on Windows in PowerShell? If I try `|| true` as-is, PowerShell says "The token '||' is not a valid statement separator in this version". What's the equivalent in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any given command, irrespective of its form, the following idiom ensures that:

- (a) execution isn't aborted and
- (b) no error is reported.

```
try {
  & $someCommand 2>$null
} catch { }
```

- Redirection `2>$null` discards *non-terminating* errors as well as *stderr* output from *external programs* (which by default do not affect the execution flow).
- [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) captures all *terminating* errors (both *statement*- and *script*-terminating errors), and by leaving the `catch` block blank, execution resumes quietly.

Note:

- For a systematic overview of PowerShell's bewilderingly complex error handling, see [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583)
- `||` and `&&` *are* available in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59039112/45375) - however:

  - they do not act on *script*-terminating errors
  - they do not themselves *silence* errors, and silencing *statement*-terminating errors isn't possible with `||` and `&&` (unless you set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` first; otherwise, you need `try` / `catch`, which cannot be meaningfully combined with `||` and `&&`).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3). However, note that this only applies to Cmdlets, not all commands. If you want to run a non-Cmdlet command, you need to wrap it in a Cmdlet:

```
Invoke-Expression -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Command "mycommand"
```

Comment: This won't prevent  _script-terminating_ errors from _aborting_ your program, and _statement-terminating_ errors won't be _silenced_, and, similarly, stderr output from external programs won't be silenced either. Also, it's generally best to [avoid `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)

Answer (score 0):

Try catch block with ErrorAction stop for regular cmdlets should work great

```
try {
    remove-item "C:\nonexistentfile" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 7 has that operator.

```
dir foo || $true

Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\js2010\foo\foo' because it does not exist.
True
```