# How to run Multiple command in Windows Powershell sequentially like second executes if first is passed?

Tags: powershell

To execute multiple commands in PowerShell we use `;` . But there is a flaw in it it executes all the commands even if one fails in between.

Is there any substitute for && in Windows Powershell ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the PowerShell equivalents of Bash's && and || operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416662/what-are-the-powershell-equivalents-of-bashs-and-operators)

Answer (score 2):

> But there is a flaw in it it executes all the commands even if one fails in between.

Try setting the appropriate preference variable - it defaults to `Continue` in `powershell.exe`:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Some-Command
Some-CommandThatMightFail
Some-OtherCommand
```

Now, if `Some-CommandThatMightFail` throws an error, execution of the containing script or function will stop and return to the caller immediately.

See the [`about_Preference_Variables` topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#erroractionpreference) in the documentation on more information about controlling error handling behavior with `$ErrorActionPreference`

---

Beware that the `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` assignment only affects the current scope - overwriting it will only affect the error action preference in the script/function/scriptblock where that assignment was executed:

```
PS C:\> $ErrorActionPreference
Continue
PS C:\> &{ 
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  # preference only changes inside this scriptblock
  $ErrorActionPreference
}
Stop
PS C:\> $ErrorActionPreference # still Continue in parent scope
Continue
```