# How to use bash's "| while read file do" and "done" in Powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell, syntax, inotify, inotifywait

What is bash's "| while read file do" and "done" in Powershell ?

For example, in bash the script is

```
cd tmp &&
inotifywait -me close_write,create,move --format %f *.tmp | while read file
do  rclone move "$file" dropbox:
done
```

What should it be like in Powershell?

I only found that `&&` could be replaced with `-and`
How about the rest?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when asking how to migrate script from lang A to B, it's a good idea to explain what the script does. That way people who can only language B can help, whilst right now one has to understand both Bash and Powershell in order to be able to answer.

Comment: Don't try to do a "mechanical" translation of bash to powershell; consider what the bash script does, and then do the same thing in powershell idiom. [There's a question on Super User that appears to do something related](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** cmdlet,  which processes each input object one by one.

With *external programs*, it is *each output line* that constitutes an object, i.e. *PowerShell streams the (stdout) output from external programs line by line* through its [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines).

```bash
# See info re *.tmp and && below.
inotifywait -me close_write,create,move --format %f *.tmp | 
  ForEach-Object { rclone move $_ dropbox: }
```

Note:

- **In PowerShell, `*.tmp` only expands to the list of matching file names *on Unix-like platforms***, which requires use of [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the modern, cross-platform edition of PowerShell.

  - **On *Windows*** (irrespective of whether you use *PowerShell (Core)* or the legacy *Windows PowerShell* edition), no such expansion is performed; replace `*.tmp` with **`(Get-Item *.tmp).Name`** there. (For more control over what gets matched, you can use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) instead of [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item)).

    - Since this technique also works on Unix-like platforms, you can use it in *cross-platform scripts*.
- The [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) is used to refer to the input line at hand.
- Enclosing variable references in `"..."` is *not* needed in PowerShell (in the case at hand, `$_` is sufficient - no need for `"$_"`), even if the values contain spaces (PowerShell neither uses word-splitting nor most of the other [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) that Bash performs).

As for the `cd tmp && ...` part, i.e. **use of `&&`**:

- You can use this syntax as-is in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which supports `&&` and `||`, the [pipeline chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators),
- However, you can *not* in *Windows PowerShell* (and `-and` is *not* a substitute)<sup>[1]</sup>; there, use something like `cd -ErrorAction Stop tmp` (`cd` is a built-in alias of [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location)) or `cd tmp; if ($?) { ... }`.

---

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816341/45375) for why.</sup>

Comment: Does the `Get-Item` bit work on unixy systems too?

Comment: @Shawn, yes, it does, so you can use this technique in cross-platform scripts - I've updated the answer to make that clear, along with mentioning `Get-ChildItem` as a more flexible alternative (if needed).