# Chain commands on the PowerShell command line (like POSIX sh &&)

Tags: shell, powershell, conditional-statements, powershell-2.0

Does PowerShell have an equivalent to this command construct from `sh` (and derivatives):

```
$ cmd1 && cmd2
```

where `cmd2` is only run when `cmd1` exits sucessfully?

I know you can combine commands with a semicolon. However, this disregards the exit status of commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct analog to && or ||. There are several discussions on alternatives though. Here is one example:

[conditional execution (&& and ||) in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251622/conditional-execution-and-in-powershell)

Comment: I realized the silliness of saying "here is the same question already answered" as I posted this answer. I've voted to close this question.

Comment: This page serves a purpose; when searching for "chain commands powershell" you get here. So you can follow your link to the real answer.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$errorActionPreference='Stop'; cmd1; cmd2
```

Comment: If the first command fails with this approach, the next will still be executed.

Comment: Have just tested this -- the second command is still executed.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I believe it should work only for native PowerShell cmdlets...

Comment: I can barely understand the positive points.  Your proposal would kill the full script, whereas "a && b" in a unix shell would not stop everything if A fails.

Comment: There is the "$?" automatic variable that stores if the command executed successfully. so cmd2 could be `if($?) { cmd2 }` I believe

Comment: It can work *if* commands throw an exception, thus breaking the processing chain. You can *usually* add `-ErrorAction Stop` to standard cmdlets so they throw an exception when failing, so further commands will not be executed.