# Is it possible to chain Powershell commands (logical chain)

Tags: powershell, syntax

In Bash,

```
command1.sh || recover.sh
command2.sh && command3.sh
```

Does powershell offer a similar, tight, construct?

The closest I have come up with:

```
command1.ps1; if ($? -ne 0) { recover.ps1 }
command2.ps1; if ($? -eq 0) { command3.ps1 }
```

Comment: Your approach is good.  See answers in these possible duplicate questions:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251622/conditional-execution-and-in-powershell
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416662/what-are-the-powershell-equivalents-of-bashs-and-operators
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104197/chain-commands-on-the-powershell-command-line-like-posix-sh

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate (my search skills failed me), and the solution is the exact one proposed by the PowerShell team for when they do implement the feature

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/9849

Comment: You could also try `try` and `catch` to replicate `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell 7 has it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7#pipeline-chain-operators

```
1/0 || 'no'
RuntimeException: Attempted to divide by zero.

no
```

Comment: Now I just eagerly await PS7 at work :(