# Multiple statements using &&

Tags: shell, powershell, syntax, cmd

What would be the equivalent statement of CMD's:

```
dir && cd ..
```

in Powershell?

I tried:

```
dir -and cd ..
```

but it throws error:

> Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'and'.
>
> At line:1 char:5
>
> `+` dir -and (cd ..)
>
> `+` CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
>
> `+` FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
>      .Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Vote here: [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3241) and here: [UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087898-implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a direct equivalent in PowerShell of cmd.exe **&&** which means "only execute right-hand side if the left-hand side succeeds." However you could write a short function to do the equivalent:

```
function IfTrue([ScriptBlock] $testExpression, [ScriptBlock] $runExpression) {
  if ( & $testExpression ) { & $runExpression }
}
```

For example:

```
IfTrue { get-childitem "fileThatExists.txt" -ea SilentlyContinue } { "File exists..." }
```

If you want for the $testExpression to produce output, the IfTrue function can be written as follows:

```
function IfTrue([ScriptBlock] $testExpression, [ScriptBlock] $runExpression) {
  & $testExpression
  if ( $? ) { & $runExpression }
}
```

Bill

Comment: Bill, I tried `IfTrue { get-childitem dir -ea SilentlyContinue } { cd .. }` but nothing displayed (no directory listing)! Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a file system item called 'dir'? 'dir' is an alias for 'get-childitem' in PowerShell.

Comment: I am afraid not. Honestly, I am new to PowerShell. Would you please explain your answer to get `dir` and `cd ..` working in single statement? Thanks.

Comment: I tried with 'IfTrue { dir -ea SilentlyContinue } { cd .. }'. The `cd ..` seems to work, but `dir` is not listing directory. I even removed `-ea SilentlyContinue`, but still no luck.

Comment: I updated my answer (see above) to include a new version of the IfTrue function. The second version of the function produces output.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
dir; if ($?) {cd ..}
```

Running `get-help about_automatic_variables | more` explains:

> $?    Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
>   TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

In PS, `dir` is just an alias for `get-ChildItem`; `cd` likewise for `Set-Location`.

**edit:** Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563600/can-i-get-to-work-in-powershell), including [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573295/1751302) straight from the horse's mouth.

Comment: Noam, thanks for the answer. This method works fine! OTOTH, is there any reason (as in conflicting with PS' foundation) that there is no support for batch operations?

Comment: Not enough upvotes [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/778798/implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has)?