# How can I use logical AND (&&) in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

In terminal I used to run two commands at once using '&&' operator. 
For example if I want to compile and run C source code I only need to write:
`gcc code.c && ./a.out`.
But unfortunately it doesn't work in Powershell. How can I do this? And I'm sorry I couldn't find any easier method to do this. Therefore, I had to post it here!
TIA!

Comment: PowerShell does not support a `&&` construct. If you want to write a command which does this for you, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8693675/712526)

Comment: (Take a look specifically at how to use [`$?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693888/712526))

Comment: Thank you. I am going to look at it. I had no idea that '&&' doesn't work in powershell. In cmd it works just fine. I am new with VSCode. They have only powershell there. It would be easier for me if it worked in PS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple statements using &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012046/multiple-statements-using)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get && to work in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563600/can-i-get-to-work-in-powershell)

Comment: Vote here: [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3241) and here: [UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087898-implement-the-and-operators-that-bash-has)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching here and there I found out '&&' doesn't work in PS. There is '-and' command in lieu of '&&'. But in my case I actually wanted to execute two command at once and it didn't work. I found a way to do this. A simple semicolon could do the work. For example: If I want to compile and run a C++ code, I just need to write `g++ /directory/code.cpp; ./a.exe`.
But if someone uses this they should be aware of that the second command will work even though the first one doesn't execute due to any error unlike the '&&' operator!

Comment: my usage was: `git pull origin master; git pull origin dev; exit`. very helpful answer. thanks @Afif.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a semicolon [;] . Something like this:

***(command);  (command)***

```
(Write-Host "this");  (Write-Host " or that")

(gcc .\code.c);  (.\a.out)
```

Comment: It's not really the same because if you use && then the right side will be executed only when left side is success.

Comment: If you really want it the same then run: `cmd /k gcc code.c && ./a.out`

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://superuser.com/a/1620000/275918) if you really need the abortive nature of the `&&` and not just "two commands, one line".

```
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"
# Line break
fakeCommand; echo "Here"
```