# How to suppress output and check whether or not a command is successful?

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, command-line-interface, windows-scripting

I am trying to write a powershell script that tests if a MySQL login is successful by using `$?` to check if an error occurs.

I also want to suppress all output - successful or not successful - from the command.

These are the things I've tried:

```
mysql -u root --password=mypass -e "show databases"
If ( $? ) {
  echo "Hooray!"
} Else {
  echo "Boo!"
}
```

This works correctly but doesn't suppress any output.

```
mysql -u root --password=mypass -e "show databases" > $null
```

Works correctly still but does not suppress the errors if the password is wrong.

```
mysql -u root --password=mypass -e "show databases" 2> $null
```

This does not work correctly. In this example, it always prints "Boo!"

```
mysql -u root --password=mypass -e "show databases" > $null 2>&1
```

This suppresses all output correctly but only ever prints "Boo!" like before.

Comment: what happens if you assign the output of the external app to a $Var?

Comment: You could do `$ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue'` before the `mysql` command, then set it back to `$ErrorActionPreference='Continue'` after your `Else` scriptblock. That should suppress any errors from displaying.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - would that have any effect on an external app?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It works on `cmd.exe /c dir c:\fakefolder`, which is what I tested with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update*:

- The `if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) ...` approach will continue to work robustly with external programs.
- However, in **PowerShell (Core) *7.2 and above*, `if ($?) ...` works robustly too** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726535/45375) for more information.

---

**Use `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` rather than `$?` to reliably detect a nonzero exit code** (typically signaling failure) reported by an external program.

You can then **use `*> $null` to categorically suppress all output** without having to worry about the impact of that redirection on `$?`:

```
mysql -u root --password=mypass -e "show databases" *>$null
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
  "Hooray!"
} else {
  "Boo!"
}
```

---

Using **a redirection that involves PowerShell's error stream - either explicitly via `2>` or implicitly via `*>`** - means that if any data is received via that stream - which in the case of calling an external program means **any output from *stderr*** - **PowerShell sets `$?` to `$false`**.

However, in the realm of external console / terminal programs, stderr isn't just used to output *error* information, but any information that isn't *data*, such as status information. Therefore, **you cannot infer failure from the presence of stderr output**.

External console / terminal programs communicate their success status solely via their *exit code*, which PowerShell reflects in the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.

It follows from the above that **`$?` can be `$false` even if the exit code is `0`, so it isn't a reliable success indicator - unlike `$LASTEXITCODE`**.