# PowerShell redirect output to Write-Host and return exit code

Tags: powershell

I need to do the following in a PowerShell script:

- call this command: `npm run build`
- return the exit code of the `npm run build` command from my script to the parent (caller) script
- print text output of the command `npm run build` but avoid returning the text from my script

So far I tried:

```
@Null = @(npm run build)
return $?
```

this hides the output completely

```
Write-Host @(npm run build)
return $?
```

this prints the output without new lines. Additionally, this prints the output all at once, after `npm run build`, and not gradually

I have PowerShell Version 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Pipe to* [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), or, because it works in a wider range of scenarios, to [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) in order to ensure *streaming* processing (reporting output as it is being received.

  - With *external programs*, whose output PowerShell only ever interprets as *text*, `Write-Host` and `Out-Host` behave identically with piped input; however, with output from *PowerShell-native commands* only `Out-Host` applies the usual, rich output formatting that you would see in the console by default, whereas `Write-Host` performs simple - and often unhelpful - `.ToString()` formatting.
- Use the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) to obtain the exit code of the most recently executed external program.

  - By contrast, the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) is an *abstract* success indicator, returning either `$true` or `$false`, which in the case of external-program calls maps exit code `0` to `$true` and any nonzero exit code to `$false`. However, in Windows PowerShell false `$false` values can occur if a `2>` redirection is involved - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623532/45375).

```
npm run build | Out-Host
return $LASTEXITCODE
```