# i have build my own configuration file but my c++ file is not running i cannt spot out error in my code please review

Tags: c++, shell, visual-studio-code

"command": "C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g3 -Wall "${file}" -o "${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe" &&"${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe""
[image: MY VS CODE]

i have build my own configuration file but my c++ file is not running i cannt spot out error in my code please review

Comment: `&&` is available in PowerShell 7. Try `-and` in an earlier version.

Comment: @Yunnosch It would not be a good answer since `-and` eats command outputs. It's well explained on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563600/can-i-get-or-and-to-work-in-powershell

Comment: @Yunnosch I like the answer "Just update PowerShell".

Comment: I do not have the hammer here, so I freely vote to consider duplicate.